# Infinite output with scanf("%[^\n]");

Tags: while-loop, scanf

Basically the code here takes some string and gives a string wihtout special character .

But when I give input, the Output gives the desired output. But it gives me infinite output.
What I want is user will give infinite input and will get desired output .

```
int main()
{

    int g= 2; char C;
    while (1)  {  
      char s[257];
      scanf("%[^\n]", s);
      int i;
      int j= strlen (s);

      for (i=0; i< j; i++){
        if( (s[i]>='a'&& s[i]<='z')|| (s[i]>='A' && s[i]<='Z') || (s[i]==' ') )
          printf ("%c",s[i]);
      }

    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `scanf("%[^\n]", s);` never consumes a `'\n'`, so input stuck when a `'\n'` is reached.  Research `fgets(s, sizeof s, stdin)`.

Comment: But I want to use scanf () ;  Is there any way to do that without fgets ()  ?

Comment: There is no _good_ way to do it with `scanf()`.  `scanf()` can be used in a hacky way.  Your call.

Comment: so it happens because  of "Buffer " right ? . Any way to clear buffer when using scanf ();  ?